# Dependency Injection - How to inject implementation of interface using Simple Injector when the implementation uses Unity for DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, simple-injector

I have two separate projects...  One project is using Simple Injector and the other Unity.  From the simple injector project, I am attempting to register the interface/implementation of a class located within the project using Unity for its DI.  I can successfully do this and gain access to the class but anything marked as a Unity [Dependency] within that class does not resolve.  I can register those dependencies to the Simple Injector container but it loses it once crossing into the class using Unity.

Example:

**Project1** (using Simple Injector)

```
public class StartUp {
    var container = new Container();
    container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IGenericRepo<>), typeof(GenericRepo));
    container.RegisterSingleton<IService, Service>();
    //more code below etc...
}

public class TestController
{
    private readonly IService service;

    public TestController(IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var test = service.GetEverything();
    }
}
```

**Project2** (using Unity)

```
public class Service : IService
{
    [Dependency]
    public IGenericRepo<ServiceObj> _serviceRepo { private get; set; }

    public IQueryable<ServiceObj> GetEverything()
    {
        return _serviceRepo.Get();
    }
}
```

With the example above, I can get to the GetEverything method within Project 2, but then the _serviceRepo dependecy is null.  Is there a way for it to know to use the registered GenericRepo<> from Project1?

Is this possible to do?

Thank you!
Ryan

Comment: Where are you registering your serviceRepo in project two?  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx

Comment: Project2 is currently does not explicitly register anything...  The only other projects used with it so far have been other Unity projects where the registration was done in the web.config or explicitly with a container in the app.

Comment: You may be able to include the first project dll in the references for the second project and then register it.

Comment: Project1 is actually a web service (web api)

Comment: Web apps in c# still have dlls

Comment: Yes.  Just seems like referencing a single web app project's dll to a class library shared amongst other projects may not be the best thing...  It looks more and more like the mixture of DI solutions is something to steer away from...  (I can certainly try it just to prove it out though but may not be a permanent solution)

Comment: You shouldn't really use a DI container in your class libraries. Take a look at this article: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/

Comment: The issue lies with the translation of objects registered using Simple Injector's container and the Unity Dependency attribute defining injection requirements for the other project's class.  I mean, if this web app was using Unity and I passed through to service or repo layers (class libraries) that were using Unity to mark classes with dependencies to be injected, that is bad practice?  I am not defining the container there, I am using what has been defined from the caller.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly Project 2 is some shared project which is used in other projects which use Unity for Dependency Injection. Unity uses property injection in this case by annoting the property with the `DependencyAttribute`.

Simple Injector is capable of doing property injection. Property injection however should only be used for optional dependencies. And as you're running into a `NullReferenceException` this dependency is not optional!

So you should move the `IGenericRepo<ServiceObj>` to the constructor of `IService`. This makes it clear to users of `IService` that it needs a repository to function correctly. This becomes especially useful when you would unittest `IService` as the constructor will in this case clearly communicates that it needs a repository.

By moving the dependency to the constructor Simple Injector will inject the repository correctly or throw an `ActivationException` if the configuration is not valid.

You can test, and I recommend doing this, by calling `container.Verify()` as you can read here: [Verify the container’s configuration](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#verify-the-container-s-configuration). This will make the application to [fail fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast).

If project 2 can't be refactored or for some other compelling reason  constructor injection is not an option, Simple Injector does support property injection. It does however not support this out-of-the-box. One of the design principles of Simple Injector is [to never fail silently](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/principles.html#never-fail-silently) and therefore only [Explicit property injection](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#property-injection) is advised. This will gives the container the opportunity to use its [Diagnostic Services](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/diagnostics.html) and fail fast if the configuration is invalid.

As you can read in the referenced documentation, there are 2 ways of doing it property injection:

1. By registering an initializer with a call to
   `container.RegisterInitializer()`
2. By implementing `IPropertySelectionBehavior`

Option 2 will let Simple Injector check the dependencies using the [Diagnostics Services](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/diagnostics.html) automatically. When verifying all 'initializers' are executed also, but the code in lambda isn't checked for lifestyles etc.

Simple Injector does not encourage its users to take a dependency on the container and it therefore does not contain any `Atrributes` which you can use out-of-the-box such as Unity has the `DependencyAttribute`.

So you have 2 options here:

1. Let project 1 also take a dependency on Unity (which it indirectly already has!, yuck) and create an implementation of `IPropertySelectionBehavior` to search for the Unity `DependencyAttribute`
2. Create your own custom `Attribute` in project 2 and annotate `_serviceRepo` which this custom attribute also.

The only difference between 1 and 2 is which attribute is searched for.
If you can't touch project 2, option 2 isn't possible. Implementing `IPropertySelectionBehavior` is straightforward:

```
// custom attribute only for option 1
public class ImportAttribute : Attribute { }

class UnityDependencyPropertySelectionBehavior : IPropertySelectionBehavior 
{
     public bool SelectProperty(Type type, PropertyInfo prop) 
     {
         return prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DependencyAttribute)).Any();
     }
}
```

You can configure the container using this custom `IPropertySelectionBehavior` by:

```
container.Options.PropertySelectionBehavior = 
               new UnityDependencyPropertySelectionBehavior();
```

To summarize:
Move the dependency to the constructor as it is not a optional dependency. In other words use constructor injection! 
If there are compelling reasons not to do this implement `IPropertySelectionBehavior`